# Finding workspace setting property name?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The workspace setting file has a extension property, how do I find what is the correct extension name to add within this property ?

Comment: go to settings, hover with the mouse over the setting you want and look at the tooltip

Comment: I need to know how to find the extension name to use in the setting *extension* property.

Comment: show the workspace setting file. Which file are you talking about: what is it's name?

Comment: The name is `<CustomName>.code-workspace`. If you type `extension` you'll get `extensions{}` I hope you can find it, otherwise here is a screen shot. https://i.postimg.cc/Qx656Nvc/extension.jpg

Comment: you can disable certain extensions for a workspace, you can control this with the buttons on each extension page. then look in the file what it stores

Comment: I know you can disable certain extensions for a workspace, but the `extension{}` property probably requires a string of extensions to disable for the workspace setting.  Where do I get the name of the extension to enter in that property ?

Comment: I *think* I may found the solution except, I'm getting an error here; `}`.

Comment: `"extensions": {"almenon.arepl"}`

Comment: the extension disabling is recorded somewhere else not in this `.code-workspace` file

Comment: I can disable extensions for a workspace setting file, by which property ?

Comment: I don't know where VSC stores that info, it stores a lot of info about a workspace somewhere in the user data folder.

Comment: I was informed that you can use for example; DB Browser for SQLite and open the `state.vscdb` file and from that file you have a *key* and a *value* and you can get the extension name via the *key* from this file ?

Answer (score 0):

The `"extensions"` section in a `name.code-workspace` file can be used to recommend extensions to a developer that opens this workspace. A new member of the team can setup some handy extensions quickly.

```
  "extensions": {
    "recommendations": ["vscode.csharp"],
    "unwantedRecommendations": ["almenon.arepl"]
  }
```